# Warrior Shield Slam Glyph

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Recently in the arena priests, druids and monk healers have been bugging me as an arms Warrior. My mortal strike says it reduces healing, but whenever I get a healer into danger a massive shield often pops up and while I break it down, he's healed back up again.

I've taken Shattering Throw to deal with Paladins and Mages using invulnerability to heal, but I'm considering trying Gladiator stance and a Glyph of Shield Slam as it says it removes one magic effect per slam.

Can anyone tell me how this magic removal effect works? If a priest uses a shield spell on himself, will the glyph kick in first removing the shield before the damage is applied, or first the damage of the shield then remove it if anything is left over.

Also is it random what magic effect it removes, or does it work on a last in first out basis?

I've looked it up on [wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/item=43425/glyph-of-shield-slam#comments) but most of their comments are about the old version of glyph that gave 10% more slam damage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research it looks like without anything informing the user, the shield slam glyph only works in defensive stance, not battle or gladiator stance

http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/15537525245

I hope this info is outdated, it's almost six months old and they couldn't add one sentence into the tooltip for this rune to let folks know not to waste a glyph in the arena.

Comment: 6 months isnt out dated.  Although I would use Wars in PvP.

Comment: The tooltip was updated. It reads: "Your Shield Slam now dispels 1 magical effect if you are in Defensive Stance."

Comment: Great, they must have read this :-)